# facebook pixel and woocommerce cart total and GTM

Tags: woocommerce, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add the total cart amount in Google Tag Manger that passes our Woocommerce cart to Facebook Pixel. We are unable to make any changes to php or add plugins as were in the process of moving site.

I know that it's possible to do with php but does ANYBODY have an idea about if its possible to use the standard FB Pixel code in GTM that can actually pass a value that is unique to each order?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can easily do this by using DOM scraping. In GTM  you can either create a custom javascript variable and in there to add the JS code which parses the cart total from the page, or, if the cart total is in HTML element that has unique id or class, you can create a DOM variable instead in GTM.

If all of these will not work you can just create a custom HTML type tag and add the javascript there which will parse the cart total from the page.